# jQuery UI and invite form

Tags: facebook, jquery-ui, fbml, facebook-fbml

I am using the following invite code on my facebook app:

```
    <fb:serverFbml>
    <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:fbml>
    <fb:request-form
            action='http://localhost:8080/home' 
            method='POST'
        invite='true'
        type='MyApp'
        content='<a href="http://www.domaint.com">Click here</a>'

        <fb:multi-friend-selector 
                actiontext="Invite your friends to join">
        </fb:request-form>
    </fb:fbml>
    </script>
    </fb:serverFbml>
```

It works fine when I am using it inside a DIV, but if I try to use jQuery UI and turn the DIV into dialog(), when a user opens the dialog it is empty (the fb:serverFbml tag does not generate the invitation form).

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't work.
The quick and dirty solution is: use an iframe instead of a div.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform you are using??(Iframe or FBML??)
I am also facing the same problem. Then i shift to fbml application and use FB:Dialog to do the same and I got it working..